# Quarto does not understand \[x^2\] as $$x^2$$

Tags: quarto

Consider the following `quarto` document:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
---

\[x^2\]
```

Can we make `quarto` to understand that `\[x^2\]` is equivalent to `$$x^2$$`.

Comment: I would file an issue, maybe it is intended - I do not know. It works with `pdf_document` though.

Comment: Done, @Julian: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/5812

Comment: Hi @PaulS, interesting question! May I ask why you need that notation?

Comment: Hi, @Quinten! I need that notation because I copy many formulas from LyX, which uses that notation. The way to make `quarto` respecting that notation seems to be inserting the formula inside a latex code block.